# clearable prop is not working for me, can anyone suggest please

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom input field which i use in my entire project.

I am trying to use clearable props in my input component so that i can clear text with one click.

but setting `clearable:"true"` is not working.

I am using

`<input :class="inputClass" v-bind="$attrs" :clearable="clearable" :value="value" @input="(e) => $emit('input', e.target.value)"/>`

and clearable's value is coming via props which i am passing from component i have to use clearable in.

Please guide me..
thanks in Advance !!!!

Comment: If you remove the v-bind bit, does the clearable pass through?  Also, please post  your declared props for the component.

Comment: hi, yes removing v-bind still pass the value as string or boolean but mistake is mine i was supposed to create clear icon and then make that work using props,
thank you so much for replying :-)

Answer (score 0):

`clearable` is not a standard HTML attribute.  You're going to have to use a custom component for this, which would be easier to use with `v-model`.. I have supplied an example of how to accomplish this using events/default value as well as an example that shows how to do this using `v-model`:

[[CodePen Mirror]](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/byKJrw)

Edit: cleaned up the code a little bit...

```js
const customInputNoVmodel = {
  template: "#custom-input-no-vmodel",
  props: {
    clearable: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(e) {
      this.$emit("input", e.target.value);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isClearable() {
      return this.clearable === true ? "search" : "text";
    }
  }
};

const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    customInputNoVmodel
  },
  data: {
    value: "Initial Value Without v-model",
    cssClasses: "my-class-one"
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput(e) {
      this.value = e;
    }
  }
});


/* *************************** */


const customInputWithVmodel = {
  template: "#custom-input-with-vmodel",
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    clearable: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    },
  },
  computed: {
    isClearable() {
      return this.clearable === true ? "search" : "text";
    },
    handleOnInput: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit('input', val)
      }
    },
  }
};

const vm2 = new Vue({
  el: "#app2",
  components: {
    customInputWithVmodel
  },
  data: {
    text: "Initial Value With v-model",
    cssClasses: "my-class-two"
  }
})
```

```css
.my-class-one {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
}

.my-class-two {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
  border: 5px solid darkmagenta;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    Not using v-model:
    <custom-input-no-vmodel 
      class="my-class-one" 
      :clearable="true" 
      :value="value"
      @input="handleInput"
    ></custom-input-no-vmodel>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div id="app2">
  <div>
    With v-model 
    <custom-input-with-vmodel 
      :class="cssClasses" 
      :clearable="true" 
      v-model="text"
    ></custom-input-with-vmodel>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- SIMULATES COMPONENT ~~WITHOUT~~ V-MODEL -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="custom-input-no-vmodel">
    <input
      v-bind="$attrs"
      :type="isClearable"
      @input="onInput"
    />
</script>

<!-- SIMULATES COMPONENT WITH V-MODEL -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="custom-input-with-vmodel">
    <input
      v-bind="$attrs"
      :type="isClearable"
      v-model="handleOnInput"
    />
</script>
```

Comment: danke schön bruder :-) 

actually mistake was mine i hadn't created a component and was doing it in wrong way but now it's working and i am emitting using input event and it works fine 

thanks for your help and suggestions :-)